# Is it possible to search for questions that have one tag and not another?

Tags: support, search

Is there any way of searching for result that contain one tag and not another?

For example I want C# results but I don't want the ones that also contain ASP.NET.

Can I search for something like this?

[c#] -[asp.net]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure you can. The `+` and `-` operators both exist in the SO search. Just [try it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+-asp.net) if you're not sure.

[image: Just try it.]

Comment: Must... Upvote... Hand-drawn-line...